# how can I parse a json object by using a loop and inserting a variable?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object as follows:

```
DISPLAY={EOS={USD={LASTTRADEID=341887636, OPEN24HOUR=$ 3.27, HIGHDAY=$ 3.51, LOW24HOUR=$ 3.26, TOTALVOLUME24HTO=$ 830.73 M, TOSYMBOL=$, LASTVOLUME=EOS 24.15, LASTMARKET=Bitfinex, LOWHOUR=$ 3.43, MKTCAP=$ 3,625.98 M, LASTUPDATE=Just now, TOTALVOLUME24H=EOS 237.50 M, VOLUMEHOURTO=$ 1,059,991.8, VOLUMEHOUR=EOS 304,460.7, CHANGEDAY=$ 0.20, SUPPLY=EOS 1,035,994,216.9, IMAGEURL=/media/1383652/eos_1.png, VOLUMEDAY=EOS 2,599,959.7, VOLUME24HOUR=EOS 3,649,420.2, MARKET=CryptoCompare Index, PRICE=$ 3.50, CHANGEPCTDAY=6.06, FROMSYMBOL=EOS, LASTVOLUMETO=$ 84.63, CHANGEPCT24HOUR=7.03, OPENDAY=$ 3.30, VOLUMEDAYTO=$ 8,793,658.5, OPENHOUR=$ 3.44, CHANGE24HOUR=$ 0.23, HIGH24HOUR=$ 3.51, VOLUME24HOURTO=$ 12,252,312.4, LOWDAY=$ 3.27, HIGHHOUR=$ 3.51}}}, RAW={EOS={USD={LASTTRADEID=341887636, OPEN24HOUR=3.27, HIGHDAY=3.51, LOW24HOUR=3.26, TOTALVOLUME24HTO=8.307307946338731E8, TOSYMBOL=USD, LASTVOLUME=24.14719568, LASTMARKET=Bitfinex, LOWHOUR=3.43, MKTCAP=3.6259797592476497E9, LASTUPDATE=1551791305, TOTALVOLUME24H=2.3750041516530967E8, VOLUMEHOURTO=1059991.8469860656, VOLUMEHOUR=304460.70931976027, CHANGEDAY=0.20000000000000018, FLAGS=4, SUPPLY=1.0359942169279E9, TYPE=5, IMAGEURL=/media/1383652/eos_1.png, VOLUMEDAY=2599959.6798382923, VOLUME24HOUR=3649420.2367477496, MARKET=CCCAGG, PRICE=3.5, CHANGEPCTDAY=6.060606060606066, FROMSYMBOL=EOS, LASTVOLUMETO=84.62626198012799, CHANGEPCT24HOUR=7.033639143730887, OPENDAY=3.3, VOLUMEDAYTO=8793658.516717305, OPENHOUR=3.44, CHANGE24HOUR=0.22999999999999998, HIGH24HOUR=3.51, VOLUME24HOURTO=1.225231238390642E7, LOWDAY=3.27, HIGHHOUR=3.51}}}}
```

I can access the price with:

```
resp.DISPLAY.EOS.USD.PRICE
```

however, I would like to do this in a loop of multiple symbols so I want to be able to do something like:

```
resp.DISPLAY' + symbol + '.USD.PRICE
```

This does not work and I get a variety of error messages including "Missing ) after argument list".

So the question is how can I build the string correctly, inserting the variable symbol, to access the elements within the JSON object?

Thank you!

Comment: Your "json object" isn't a json object...

Comment: You are neither *parsing* JSON, nor is this even JSON. Both of these have strict definition - parsing refers to reading a value usually from a string to produce a new value. For example `parseFloat` reads a string and returns a number. And `JSON.parse` reads a string of JSON and returns a JavaScript object. Which leads to the next part - a JavaScript object is *not* JSON. JSON is a serialisation format which is always text. If you interact with it in any other way than text, it's not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resp.DISPLAY[symbol].USD.PRICE
```

Comment: without the ''. anyway, thank you. and apologies for apparently "duplicating" the question.